# How to check if the number of ones is greater than the number of zeroes in a numpy array without traversing whole array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given a Boolean numpy nd-array, how can I found if the total number of `ones` is greater than the total numbe of `zeros` in the array without traversing the whole array with nested for loops. I meant a function in-line with `any()` and `all()`. Say `max_bool()` which works as follows:

```
def max_bool(array):
    return array.ones => array.zeros
```

Traversing is not an option as the dimensions of arrays, I intended to work with have diverse unpredictible dimensions and can be too large. I am not concerned about the exact number of `ones` & `zeros` either. Just that if array has more `ones` or `zeros`, even if the number of `ones` is just one greater than the number of `zeros`. Any help?

Comment: How about summing the entire array and comparing the result to the array's half-length ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simplest way I can think of:

```
def max_bool(array):
    return array.mean() >= .5
```